# What is the difference between emacs -Q -u [my-user] and emacs -Q -l [my-init-file.el]

Tags: init-file, start-up

I have all my emacs config in `.emacs.d/init.el`. The first command in that file is:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

When I start emacs with `emacs -Q -u [my-user]` it works fine.

But when I start it with `emacs -Q -l ~/.emacs.d/init.el` I get the error `Symbol’s value as variable is void: package-archives`.

I know that I can add `(require 'package)` at the top of init.el to solve this problem. However, I'm trying to understand why I don't get that error with `emacs -Q -u [my-user]`.
Besides I encounter other similar problems down the line with `-Q -l ~/.emacs.d/init.el` which are not present with `-Q -u [my-user]`.

What could `-u [my-user]` load that is not in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`?

I had a look at [The Emacs Initialization File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and [How Emacs Finds Your Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html). It lists several other possibilities for init files. None seems present on my system.

Specifically, none of these files exist:

- ~/.emacs.el
- ~/.emacs
- ~/.config/emacs/

I don't seem to have a site-wide `default.el`. Anyway the docs say that it would be loaded after my `init.el` so it would not explain why emacs chokes on the 1st line of that file.

I don't have `site-start.el` either. Confirming this, it makes no difference whether I append `--no-site-file` to the above commands.

In the [Startup Summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html) I saw this:

> 7. It calls the function package-activate-all to activate any optional Emacs Lisp package that has been installed. See Packaging Basics. However, Emacs doesn’t activate the packages when package-enable-at-startup is nil or when it’s started with one of the options ‘-q’, ‘-Q’, or ‘--batch’.

I still don't understand why it works with `-Q -u [my-user]` and not with `-Q -l [my-init-file]`.

I have GNU Emacs 27.1 built from source on Debian Buster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weird thing is that `-Q -u [user]` loads an init file at all. I'd call that a bug, but it's probably been this way for decades.

Given that it does, I suspect there's no difference between these:

- `emacs`
- `emacs -q -u "$USER"`

I.e. you've *reverted* the `--no-init-file` (aka `-q`) behaviour by specifying an init file (although again, I find that surprising).

If that's correct, then the only difference to `emacs -Q -u "$USER"` would be the difference between `-q` and `-Q`.  As you can see from `emacs --help`:

```
--quick, -Q                 equivalent to:
                              -q --no-site-file --no-site-lisp --no-splash
                              --no-x-resources
```

Conversely `emacs -Q -l [my-init-file]` *isn't* overriding `--no-init-file` and so you can expect the behaviour you've quoted from the documentation to hold.

Note also that `-l` isn't processed until later in the start-up sequence, and so even if the options you passed didn't have additional effects, loading a file with `-l` would not *necessarily* give the same outcome as Emacs loading it as an init file.

Comment: What I still don't understand is why I get the error regarding `package-archives` being void when I start with `-Q -l`. I understand that it is because `package.el` is not initialized, but then what does initialize it when I run with `-Q -u`? I don't initialize it at all in my init.el.

Comment: Emacs does it for you.  You quoted it yourself -- Emacs calls `package-activate-all` when there's an init file.  Those docs don't account for this (somewhat unusual) scenario, but by adding `-u` you've caused there to be an init file *despite* using `-Q`, and so packages are initialized.

Comment: For clarity, by "when there's an init file" I mean "the `--no-init-file` option is not in effect".  The init file itself doesn't need to exist.  The `-u` option is evidentially preventing `--no-init-file` from being set, despite `-Q` being passed.